# ¿Por qué mi aplicación de R shiny no renderiza correctamente?

Tags: r, windows10, shiny

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación shiny que trabaja con mapas y datos del último censo realizado en mi país, sin embargo, desde que actualicé R a su versión 3.6.1, el tema por defecto de shiny no se renderiza, en su lugar solo se ejecuta como una página básica de solo texto.

A modo de ejemplo, entrego estas imágenes, primero muestro como es que se ejecuta en mi equipo y después como debería verse :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí 2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que es irrelevante colocar el código de este trabajo porque esto ocurre con cualquier aplicación, independiente de su código (el segundo lo ejecuté en Rstudio cloud), no soy una persona experta en programación o informática, así que no entiendo del todo cuales son los procesos que el lenguaje realiza para poder finalmente ejecutar, y estoy seguro de que todo esto ocurrió por alguna configuración que cambió en mi equipo o en mi sistema operativo, así que, como llevo varios meses estancado en este problema sin encontrar una solución, les comparto mi duda.

EDIT: SE SOLUCIONÓ!

Acabo de actualizar todos mis paquetes de R (shiny entre ellos) y ahora vuelve a estar todo bien, voy mantener la pregunta abierta en caso de que alguien esté pasando por lo mismo, si tiene claro qué fue lo que pasó y quiere compartirlo, le agradezco de antemano que lo haga. Agradezco también a la persona quien me respondió.

Comment: Por las dudas, revisa que en tu navegador no tengas deshabilitado Javascript.

Comment: Acabo de revisar y al parecer lo tengo activado, en cualquier caso había probado utilizando otros navegadores, pero las aplicaciones fallan en todos estos, inclusive falla en el asistente de visualización que entrega R studio.

Comment: Bien si incluso en el viewer propio no te funciona, probaría la reinstalación con `install.packages("shiny")`. Sino habría que mirara el código html generado, abres la app en un browser e inspeccionas el código html, al comienzo tienes la carga de una serie de scripts de javascript, verifica haciendo click sobre los mismos si efectivamente son accesibles. Revisa también y reinstala los paquetes adicionales, seguramente en el html tienes algo como esto `<script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[3.4.1];shiny[1.4.0];selectize[0.11.2];bootstrap[3.4.1]</script>`

Comment: Revisa esas dependencias y vuelvelas a instalar.

Comment: A pesar de que ya no puedo revisar si es que efectivamente esa era la falla, agradezco sus respuestas, me ayuda a mi o a cualquiera en mi situación en saber qué caminos seguir en caso de que vuelva a ocurrir

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas podido solucionar. Saludos.